# How can I access my task.py file inside my unittest.py?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, python-unittest, jetbrains-toolbox

I'm using jetbrains academy with pycharm and I'm trying to build a course with automatic checking with unittests in python. Here what I get when creating a default task of type "edu":

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yshz.png)

When I look at the default test_task.py (I didn't change a single line), the problem is already obvious:

```
import unittest

from task import summe


# todo: replace this with an actual test
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(summe(1, 2), 3, msg="adds 1 + 2 to equal 3")
```

Line 3 doesn't work because task is not visible from test_task.py. I can't/don't want to change the structure because of the course structure. What can I do? And why is there no documentation from Jetbrains?

Edit: And why would Jetbrains give us a template which is not working, am I missing something?

Thx for any help
Reto

I already tried relative imports (from .. import task), obviously don't work. I also tried some path-meddling with sys.path.append('../task1'), no results. It's amazing something seemingly that simple is so complicated...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to get files from higher directories. You can use test_task.py in task.py by:

```
import tests.test_task.py
```

But I think it's not possible to do it the other way around. What's possible tho, is using the sys and os module to create a directory where your task.py is stored and import it like this. This website explains it:

[https://favtutor.com/blogs/import-from-parent-directory-python#:~:text=Conclusion,Python%20with%20many%20subdirectories%20simple](https://favtutor.com/blogs/import-from-parent-directory-python#:%7E:text=Conclusion,Python%20with%20many%20subdirectories%20simple).

I hope this helps!

Comment: So you say basically Jetbrains gives us a template solution which doesn't work in the first place? All their examples and explanations are written in Java (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10081-jetbrains-academy/docs/framework-lessons-guide-for-course-creators.html), but they do "support" PyCharm...what a mess:(

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...I just tried again, and it works like a charm. You just have to ignore the PyCharm IDE telling you it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm you can add content routes. Add the parent folder of task.py as a source.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html#create-content-root